# Tesseract-ocr, baseapi.h fatal error: platform.h file not found

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract, leptonica

I am working on engineering work on license plate recognition and therefore started from a simple code. Namely, I downloaded all the libraries or OpenCV, Tesseract and Leptonica but when you try to compile I have a problem with the file baseapi.h located in the library Tesseract.

Compiles the following command: **g++ main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -ltesseract**

Error The compiled: **tesseract-ocr/api/baseapi.h:27:22: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory**

The beginning of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "leptonica-1.69/src/allheaders.h" 
#include "tesseract-ocr/api/baseapi.h" 
using namespace std;
using namespace tesseract;
using namespace cv;
```

...

Comment: If I remember correctly (did that long time ago) you need to manually move some headers (like platform.h) one folder up (or down...)

Comment: **Do not add C tag for C++ questions!** Your code is C++.

Comment: Sorry, Olaf ;)
Okey, I'll try Miki

Answer (score 0):

try to install dev packages

```
$ sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-dev
$ sudo apt install libleptonica-dev
```